# Search Bar Cancel Button not reloading original table view and data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

The search and everything else works fine except when I click Cancel on the search bar, an empty screen appears with the empty search bar on it and the navigation bar of the original table view. The original, unfiltered, array from Core Data is not reloaded. I have checked the "Shows cancel button" in the storyboard. I have researched many posts and articles, but no suggestions have worked. The console messages show that after the Cancel button is pressed, among other messages I see the "Events after Fetch:" is executed twice. The second (last) time it has all my managed objects/events in it, but then "filtered array:" is blank, "events:" is blank, "events.self.count:" = 0, searchBarText is blank, self.events.count = 0.

EventViewController.h file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

    @interface EventViewController: UITableViewController       <UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>


    {
        IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    }

        @end
```

EventViewController.m file:

```
#import "EventViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "EventDetailViewController.h"

@interface EventViewController ()    

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *events;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id< UISearchResultsUpdating > searchResultsUpdater;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchBar *_searchBar;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id< UISearchControllerDelegate > delegate;

//@property(nonatomic, assign, getter=isActive) BOOL active;

@end


@implementation EventViewController
NSMutableArray *events;


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    NSLog(@"Setting up managed object context");

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;

}



- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{

    // Fetch the events from persistent data store

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Event"];

    self.events = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];


      NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text];

   self.events = [[self.events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];


 }


- (BOOL)shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(UISearchController *)searchController


{


    return YES;

 }



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = true;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

}



- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the events from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    self.events = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}




- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    self.searchController.searchBar.text = nil;
    [self.searchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];       

    }


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {


    return 1;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    {

        return [self.events count];
    }
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [event valueForKey:@"name"]]];

        {

        event = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSManagedObject *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [event valueForKey:@"name"]]];
    }

    return cell;

}



// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove event from table view
        [self.events removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Navigation


// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)send


{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateEvent"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedEvent = [self.events objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];

        EventDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.event = selectedEvent;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the cancel function you should not filter the array, so you should not execute the lines i mentioned below at that time, for this you may check the length of `self.searchController.searchBar.text` or you can set a boolean to check if cancel is clicked or text is entered in the textfield

```
  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text];

  self.events = [[self.events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Wow - thanks! I had tried something like that before, but had the wrong combination I was checking. I now did this in the searchBarCancelButtonClicked:  self.searchController.searchBar.text = @"";  and in updateSearchResultsForSearchController if ((self.searchController.searchBar.text.length > 0)) I performed the whole routine else without the two lines you listed and it worked! Thanks SO much! Just one more question - If no results are found, the blank table appears, but should it also state "no match found"? I am going to look into how to up-vote you!

Comment: yes, it should say no match found, for the most easy way you can put a label in the view with 'no match found' and keep it hidden initially, when array count is 0 hide the tableview and show the label and when count is greater you can show the tableview and hide the label

Comment: If this answer helps you can mark answer as correct, for the upvote you can do by ticking the up arrow beside count in the left side of my answer but it will be shown only when you have 15 rep more ref:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Altho a Swift version would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

in your searchBarCancelButtonClicked add self.searchController.active = NO;
before before reloadData

Create search controller in code, don't drop any search controls in storyboard

Add UISearchBarDelegate in .h

Add property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Comment: I have added the results of my trace to the end of my post. Also, in the Storyboard I used the Search Bar and Search Display Controller object - I am wondering if that could be contributing to my problem. I could add pics of the connections if needed. I am a beginner and really stuck. Thank you.